# Transform math string equation

Tags: javascript, regex, math, equations

Trying to find the best and most flexible way (parser, regex, etc..) to take in a string math equation that uses percentages and output a new string equation that changes the percentages in certain scenarios. It'll have to be flexible because of the many permutations an equation may have.

The rule if a non percentage number is added, subtracted, divided, etc by a percentage it expands the percentage to equal the the percentage of that following operand.

For example..
`120 + 12%` 
would output..
`120 + 12/100 * 120` .
so that 120 is increased by 12% of 120.

but `120% * 120%` .
would still equal 144%.

In these string equations, % never means modulus. Modulus is handled by `mod` operator.

Any many many other combinations, not just these would have to work as well. What would be be the best technical choice to handle such a task?

This particular job is done in Javascript.

Comment: `120 12/100 * 120` ... can you better explain what this actually means?  Also, can `%` ever mean modulus in your math string?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Write out all the rules for well-formed equations as a formal grammar. Then write a parser. If your grammar allows for parentheses, then I'd definitely stay away from regex, and would probably go with a parser regardless.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's overkill for your use-case, but [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) is a popular parser generator (you feed an input grammar) that can be used to generate files that target [Node and browser JavaScript](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md). As Ted Hopp suggested, your primary work is to use their grammar syntax to create a set of rules.

Comment: Is something like this possible? `((120))+12%`, and `100+(3*4-2)%`?